# How to automate photoshop from the command line

Tags: command-line, adobe-photoshop, batch, automation, processing

I have a tool which writes some tags to a photo. On some photos it fails, and for those I want to open them in photoshop, and resave it with maximum quality (jpeg). Ideally I would like to do that from the command line as then I can just do:

```
for %a in (*.jpg) do mytool.exe "%a" || [AUTOMATED PROCESS HERE]
```

I tried first just doing photoshop.exe "%a" but it seems photoshop doesn't even accept a command line argument for what photo to open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to do this.  It is a suite of command line tools for image manipulation.  [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) is the one you want for this job.

```
mogrify -quality 100 *.jpg
```

There are several ways to set the [quality](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality), this just shows one.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct -- Photoshop does not allow command line options to do the things you're trying to do. Photoshop does, however, support macros which can be recorded and then run in batch process.

Comment: Photoshop can also be automated from it's COM interface via WSH (vbscript/jscript etc)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do this very easy in Photoshop with the creation of small executable tasks that run Photoshop macros (actions). This is called a Photoshop Droplet

http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/photoshop/how-to-create-droplets-in-photoshop-cs6/